# Text isn't selectable on website, possibly masked by css

Tags: css, css-animations

Currently I'm developing a simple website on which a experiment a lot with modern CSS techniques like animations and transition. But after implementing some carefully planned animations, suddenly my body texts aren't selectable anymore. I think some element is masking the text, but I can't find it. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would help me a lot.

You can check the dev version on [the-outsiders.nl](http://the-outsiders.nl), below is a snippet of the sass I'm using.

Thx in advance!

```
.slider {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: -1;
margin: 0;

li {

    span { 
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        color: transparent;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-repeat: none;
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: -1;
        @include animation(0s, 25s, imageAnimation); 
    }

    div { 
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 30px;
        right: 0px;
        min-width: 20em;
        text-align: left;
        opacity: 1;
        color: #fff;
        @include animation(0s, 25s, titleAnimation); 

    }

}
}

.slider,
.slider:after { 
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1; 
}


@include keyframe(imageAnimation) { 
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1; @include transform(scale(1.025)); animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    100% { opacity: 1; @include transform(scale(1.15)); animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
}

@include keyframe(titleAnimation) { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: What @j08691 said. Also, use developer tools or firebug to inspect the elements.

Comment: Sorry I didn't provide the code, I edited my question to provide some. I did use the inspector for debugging, but I missed the .slider:after z-index value. Guess I'm not as sharp as I could be after a full day of work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`slider` has `z-index: -1;` in two places.

Once you take out those two z-index, you should be able to select the bottom text.

[image] [image]

Comment: Why do I always feel so stupid after reading the answer. Totally missed the .slider:after class. Thanks Win!

Answer (score 0):

I am having a hard time determining what you are asking.  But if you are concerned that one control is masking another, you can determine if another element is masking your input by setting the background color of the potential overlaying item to something like bright green.  It should then be obvious when something is on top of something else.